# Can someone explain this JavaScript switch code to me?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I don't really understand the `switch` here, from what I know the `switch` function is supposed allow me to write certain cases and each `case` is supposed to redirect me to a function, this is an example from my college slides, are the cases numbered "1234","12345", "123" or are those the passwords the user might enter?

```
function login() {
    var username = document.myForm.userName.value;
    var password = document.myForm.pass.value;
    if ((username.length == 0) || (password.length == 0)) {
        window.alert("Empty user name or password!");
    } else {
        switch (password) {
            case "12345":
                window.location = "page1.html";
                break;
            case "1234":
                window.location = "page2.html";
                break;
            case "123":
                window.location = "page3.html";
                break;
            default:
                window.alert("Invalid Password");
                document.myForm.pass.select();
        } // end switch case
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: What specifically is the confusion? The user can enter anything, what happens is based on what they enter: program flow "switches" based on the password. (Unrelated, but those are strings-containing-numbers, not numbers.)

Comment: Switch is taking the value of `password` -  each case is a possible value of `password`,  and you'd enter that section if they match; failing that, you go to default

Comment: Forget the word "password". It is misleading. It just serves as a choice for which page the user wants to go to. Anyone could of course read the JavaScript code to know which choices are available.

Comment: *each `case` is supposed to redirect me to a function* — no, that's not accurate. It *may* be what the cases do, but the code in a `case` clause can be anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As you suggested, those are passwords the user might enter.**

If the user enters “12345”, the switch statement will enter that case, setting `window.location` to page1.html.

“1234” results in `window.location` being set to to page2.html, and so on.

Note that, if the user enters any value not specified in the switch cases (“12345”, “1234, “123”), the “default” case will be activated, executing `window.alert(“Invalid Password”);` as well as `document.myForm.pass.select();`

Answer (score 1):

The `switch (password)` means that the variable `'password'` is being checked in the current switch case.

So - in case that the password equals what's in the `case` - the lines of code in that case's scope will be executed until they reach the `break`.

for example :

```
var x = 'lala'
switch(x){
  case 'lala':
    foo()
    break;
  case 'lolo':
    bar()
    break;
}
```

so foo() is going to be executed.

Hope this helped!